# Squash two Git commits in the middle of history without interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm in the process of converting an old SVN repository over to Git, which includes trying to get all of the branches/tags in all of the right places. That part is going pretty well, but there are times where I want to add a commit in history in my script that I later want to squash with the next commit. The problem is that I'm not grabbing the commits one by one, but as a large group so I can't squash them as I pull them out of the SVN repository. In the end, my repository looks like this:

```
* (branch_2, HEAD) commit 5
* commit 4
* commit 3
* SQUASH ME!
* (branch_1) commit 2
* commit 1
```

I want to be able to squash `commit 3` with `SQUASH ME!`, which is obviously easy with an interactive rebase, but more challenging from within a script. The main problem I seem to have is that while it's easy to checkout `branch_1` or any commit before it, it's hard to programmatically ask for the commit *after* it and it's hard for me to predict how many commits back from `branch_2` I need to go. I really want to be able to do something like:

```
git checkout branch_1+2
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Take a look at the "onto" option for the rebase command for doing things like squashing without having to be interactive (great for scripts): http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/git-rebase-onto

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink That's not exactly what I'm looking for. That post emphasizes being able to drop commits. I want to squash (or fixup) the `SQUASH ME!` commit because I do want the changes. I just want them to be combined with `commit 3`.

Comment: It might be simpler to let the script act as the editor during interactive rebase.

Comment: @coredump It would definitely be simpler to just do the interactive rebase, but then that defeats the point of the script. I want to be able to give this to someone else and let them do it without any interference.

Comment: @WesleyBland I mean, let the script be the one who interacts with git, by setting  GIT_EDITOR to a program of your choice. Your program opens the file, erase/modify some lines and exit. Wrap the whole thing in another script: `GIT_EDITOR=./scripts/editor-bot git rebase --interactive $0` or something equivalent that suits your needs.

Comment: I just read this, and realised that my answer says the exact same thing, and I even wrote the script for you. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are speaking about is not a **squash**, but a **fixup**, because the squash will ask you for the commit msg interactively, whereas **the fixup uses the commit message from the HEAD commit**.

Here's a script that does it without intervention.

The script : `/usr/bin/git-fixup`

```
#/bin/bash
# This command fixesup one commit onto his parent
set -e

# We need a commit from the first argument of that command
commit=${1:?No commit given as first argument}
startingbranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

# Checkout the parent of the asked commit
git checkout "$commit"
git checkout HEAD~

# Merge the commit into it's parent, keeping the commit message of the parent
git merge --squash "$commit"
git add .
git add --update
git commit --amend --no-edit

# Store the current commit
newcommit=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# Rebase the starting branch onto the new commit
git checkout "$startingbranch"
git rebase "$newcommit"
```

Use it with

```
git fixup <commit-id>
```

For example, if your history is:

```
ce0e2fd (master, HEAD) commit 4
72ab3c4 commit 3
8150939 commit 2
301c1e1 commit 1
```

You can do `git fixup 72ab3c4` which will merge together "commit 3" and "commit 2" as a commit with the message "commit 2", and place you back on the master branch.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `set -e` in order to abort when the working directory is dirty. The first `git checkout` will complain and the whole script will exit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've put that

Comment: @edi9999 I see you are offering a script called `git-fixup` and then suggesting to use the command `git fixup` (with a space) -- is that a 4 year old typo?  If not, please explain how these are to be used together.

Comment: Hello @JonathanCross, no it is not a typo, this is a git specific thing (although I could not find this in the docs). When you run git anything, if `git-anything` exists in your path it will run that instead. That is what git-extras does for example : https://github.com/tj/git-extras/tree/master/bin

Comment: @edi9999 Thanks for sharing, git-extras looks useful. However it is not part of git, but rather helper scripts for git that you installed on your personal machine.  It won't work for others (unless they also install the helpers).  Interestingly, `git-fixup` is not in that list you sent.

Answer (score 7):

From `git rebase --help`:

> **--autosquash**
>
> When the commit log message begins with "squash! ..." (or "fixup! ..."), and there is a commit whose title begins with the same
>   ..., automatically modify the todo list of rebase -i
>   so that the commit marked for squashing comes right after the commit to be modified, and change the action of the moved commit
>   from pick to squash (or fixup).
>
> This option is only valid when --interactive option is used.

That looks like it'll do half of what you want, if the input is in the correct form.

The other half is preventing it launching the interactive editor. Luckily, the editor is configurable, so we can just set it to something harmless.

Try this:

```
env EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autosquash <from-here>
```

Setting the editor to `true` (a tool that simply exits successfully) is enough to convince git to proceed with the default rebase settings, which the auto-squash should have set to something useful.

---

Alternatively, if `--autosquash` doesn't do what you want, you can set `EDITOR` to any script that you like:

```
env EDITOR=mysquasher.sh git rebase -i <from-here>
```

The script can do anything you need, but in your case it need only find every line that contains `"SQUASHME!"`, and alter the `"pick"` on the following line to read `"fixup"`. This can probably be most easily achieved with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

awk -- 'BEGIN {dosquash=0}
        dosquash==1 {gsub(/^pick/, "fixup"); dosquash=0}
        /SQUASHME/ {dosquash=1}
        {print}' "$1" > /tmp/tmp.$$

mv /tmp/tmp.$$ "$1"
```

Comment: Do you have `VISUAL` set, or any other suspicious looking environment variables?

Comment: Try setting `GIT_EDITOR` instead. Git responds to at least `EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, and `GIT_EDITOR` (for me), but I assume the latter is checked first.

Comment: You do have the `env` and `git` commands all togther on the same line, right?